# PageControl page handling

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to use a UIPageControl with my UIScrollView. It seems that i'm doing something improperly cause the page is always set to one.

This is my ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    scrollView.delegate = self;

    UIImageView *imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorialScreen1.png"]];
    imgView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 436);
    [scrollView addSubview:imgView1];

    UIImageView *imgView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorialScreen2.png"]];
    imgView2.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 436);
    [scrollView addSubview:imgView2];

    UIImageView *imgView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorialScreen3.png"]];
    imgView3.frame = CGRectMake(640, 0, 320, 436);
    [scrollView addSubview:imgView3];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(960, 436);

    pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];

    [pageControl setNumberOfPages:3];
    [pageControl setCurrentPage:0];    
}
```

And here is my UIScrollView Delegate Method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollViewx{
    NSLog(@"%f",scrollView.contentOffset.x);
    NSLog(@"%f",(scrollViewx.contentOffset.x / 320));
    pageControl.currentPage = ((scrollViewx.contentOffset.x / 320));
}
```

And here is y .h file:

```
@interface TutorialViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

@end
```

Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't change? Of course i made sure my UIPageControl is connected to its instance.

Appreciate your help...

Comment: What are the logs in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating showing? And if you add a NSLog("UIPageControl page: %d", pageControl.currentPage); at the end of scrollViewDidEndDecelerating what does that show?

Comment: And when you try to scroll such that the 320 goes to zero or 640, what then? -- Extra question: you seem to be re-allocating and intialising your page control. If you've connected it in IB, then doing this will create a new instance and break you connection.

Comment: I scrolled back to zero and it shows 0.00, 0.00 and 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. the dot isn't changing because you've created a new UIPageControl instead of using the one you set up in IB. Take out: `pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];`